# Loading data in https and http

Tags: http, web, server, https, host

I have a website and free SSL Certification from my web server.
why do the data loaded on http & https is different?

**why don't loading "style.css" file in https? but this file load in http protocol.
**
thanks.
I am very trying and searching the web, but i don't receive good data.

Comment: First you MAY redirect all `HTTP` to `HTTPS`. Please show the `<script>` tag you use for `HTTPS`?

Comment: I meant the `<style>` tag...

Comment: My problme is solved by your anwser. thanks for you :)

All Germany's kids is cool !